# DROPDOWN MENU- changing where it opens

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, navigationbar

This is my html code below:-

```css
.header {
 background-color: #b6b4b4;
 padding: 5px;
}
.logo {
 border-radius: 30px;
 float: left;
}
#social {
 width: 50px;
 border-radius: 100%;
 float: right;
}
.navigatbar {
 margin-top: -16px;
}
#navigat {
 display: inline;
 color: #b6b4b4;
 font-size: 21px;
 font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
 margin: 0 10px;
 padding: 0 3px 0 3px;
}
.topnav {
 background: #ffffff;
}
a {
 color: #2ad2c9;
}
.active {
 background-color: #e8e8e8;
}
.droplinks {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  min-width: 140px;
  display: none;
}
.droplinks a {
  padding: 10px;
  display: block;
}
.dropbutton:hover .droplinks {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<body link="#008080" vlink="#66b2b2">
<div class="header">
 <img src="images/logo.jpg" class="logo">
 <a href="#" target="blank"><img src="slike/yt.png" id="social"></a>
 <a href="#" target="blank"><img src="slike/ig.png" id="social"></a>
 <a href="#" target="blank"><img src="slike/fb.png" id="social"></a>
</div>
<div class="navigatbar">
 <ul class="topnav">
  <li class="active" id="navigat"><a href="index.html">Početna</a></li>
  <li class="dropbutton" id="navigat"><a href="fitnes.html">Fitnes</a>
    <div class="droplinks">
     <a href="#">Treninzi</a>
     <a href="#">Dijagnostika</a>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li id="navigat"><a href="skolica.html">Školica sporta</a></li>
  <li id="navigat"><a href="boks.html">Boks</a></li>
  <li id="navigat"><a href="personal.html">Personalni treninzi</a></li>
  <li id="navigat"><a href="ishrana.html">Ishrana i zdravlje</a></li>
  <li class="dropbutton" id="navigat"><a href="rehab.html">Prevencija i rehabilitacija</a>
   <div class="droplinks">
    <a href="#">Prevencija</a>
    <a href="#">Rehabilitacija</a>
    <a href="#">Kiropraktika</a>
    <a href="#">Kinezitejping</a>
   </div>
  </li>
  <li id="navigat"><a href="kontakt.html">Kontakt</a></li>
 </ul>
</div>
</body>
```

Now, here is the problem: my dropdown menus work, but both of them open on the left side of the navigation bar, under the first

element. Where have I gone wrong?
I've tried to add some margin-left and it works, butthe problem is that it moves both of them for the same amount of pixels, and they're still opening on the same place. I could give different classes to them and add them a different margin-left, but I'm kind of sure that that is not the only possible solution. 
Can anyone help me, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your CSS in 2 places:

```
#navigat {
    display: inline;
    color: #b6b4b4;
    font-size: 21px;
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
    margin: 0 10px;
    padding: 0 3px 0 3px;
    position: relative; /* add this line */
}
.droplinks {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    min-width: 140px;
    display: none;
    left: 0; /* add this line */
    z-index: 1; /* add this line */
}
```

Comment: Wow, thank you very much, it works! I'm working on this all day, and I didn't remember to try this! Thanks!

Comment: Welcome and I am glad that I could help :-) Maybe I can draw your attention to the the link that I posted at the beginning of my profile?

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your css

```
.dropbutton { position: relative; }
```

Absolutely positioned elements are positioned relative to their first ancestor that have a non-static position. `position: static` is the default for all elements, unless otherwise supplied.

That means in your case, the drop down menus are both positioned relative to the body of the document. What you want, is to position them relative to the button that triggers them. The above suggestion should take care of that.

Also, use `left`, `top`, `right` and `bottom` instead of `margin` to position your dropdowns.